# Expected: end of statement

Tags: vb6

After declaring this line I get this compilation error: `Expected: End of Statement`. Can someone help me?

```
Dim file2 As Stream : file2 = New FileStream(modGeneral.pdfPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
```

Comment: It looks like vb.net. What language exactly are you programming with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
file2 = New FileStream...
```

There is no such object as `FileStream` in VB6.  It looks like you have mixed VB.NET with VB6.